# excel if a name in column a has the same date as column b add together all results in column c

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sumifs

I've been having a problem that I can't seem to solve fully. Basically, I have a range of data that looks like this.

```
START DATE(UTC)      DURATION (mins)     NAME
--------------------|-------------------|------
5/08/2018            5                   Home
5/08/2018            1017.616667         Home
5/08/2018            493.9166667         Sleep
5/08/2018            19.6                Mindfulness
6/08/2018            8.55                Transport
6/08/2018            115.1333333         Gym
6/08/2018            12                  Transport
6/08/2018            6.483333333         Home
6/08/2018            6.75                Home
6/08/2018            1170.716667         Home
6/08/2018            510.2166667         Sleep
```

My goal is to collate the durations that have a matching name and occur on the same date and then apply a formula to a largish data set. So I should be able to get 1022 for "Home" for the 5/08/2018 and 1184 for "Home" on 6/08/18. I've tried a sumif but only managed to add up all those that occurred within 30 days.

Any help with this would be awesome

Thank you

Comment: You can use sumifs with multiple conditions.

Comment: what would that look like? `=SUMIFS($AH$2:$AH$12,$AD$2:$AD$12,"*"&AD16&"*",$AI$2:$AI$12,AI2)` This is what I currently have with AD16 containing a date. in this case 5/08/2018  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pivot table: `Insert` > `Pivot Table`.
Put Name into the `Columns` field, Start Date into the `Rows` field and `Sum` of Duration in the `Values` field.

Comment: Oh nice, that did it! Thank you! I'm trying to use these totals to see how they affect another entry i.e. does spending more time at home increase or decrease another variable (thinking I'll use linear regression but still trying to work it out). Will, I still be able to do this with the data in a pivot table?